# How to call the Values function in aws-sdk-go-v2?

Tags: aws-sdk-go

I am writing a program that uses aws-sdk-go-v2 and receives a string input from the user that determines what storage class to use when storing an object in S3. I have to validate that the input is an allowed value, and if it is not, I give a list of allowed values.

In v1 of aws-sdk-go, you could call [`s3.StorageClass_Values()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#StorageClass_Values) to enumerate the allowed `StorageClass` values.

```golang
func StorageClass_Values() []string
```

Example:

```golang
// v1.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(s3.StorageClass_Values())
}
```

```
$ go run v1.go
[STANDARD REDUCED_REDUNDANCY STANDARD_IA ONEZONE_IA INTELLIGENT_TIERING GLACIER DEEP_ARCHIVE OUTPOSTS]
```

But in aws-sdk-go-v2, types were introduced for StorageClass and the function that enumerates the values requires a type to be called.

From [the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3@v1.17.0/types#StorageClass.Values):

```golang
func (StorageClass) Values() []StorageClass
```

This seems to require an initialized variable to call? Why is this the case? What's the idiomatic way to call this function?

I've managed to get it to work in two different ways, and both seem wrong.

```golang
// v2.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    s3Types "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3/types"
)

func main() {
    // Create uninitialized StorageClass variable and call .Values()
    var sc s3Types.StorageClass
    fmt.Println(sc.Values())

    // One-liner that uses one of the types directly:
    fmt.Println(s3Types.StorageClassStandard.Values())
}
```

```
$ go run v2.go
[STANDARD REDUCED_REDUNDANCY STANDARD_IA ONEZONE_IA INTELLIGENT_TIERING GLACIER DEEP_ARCHIVE OUTPOSTS]
[STANDARD REDUCED_REDUNDANCY STANDARD_IA ONEZONE_IA INTELLIGENT_TIERING GLACIER DEEP_ARCHIVE OUTPOSTS]
```

The one-liner is better because it is more concise, but I have to reference one of the storage classes, which doesn't have a particular meaning, so it feels wrong.

Which one should I use and why?

I wish they had simply kept the calling convention from v1. The `Values()` function in v2 doesn't use the type sent to it.

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with you that this is an odd api design. The `(StorageClass) Values()` is not using the receiver. This is the sdk-code:

```golang
func (StorageClass) Values() []StorageClass {
    return []StorageClass{
        "STANDARD",
        "REDUCED_REDUNDANCY",
        "STANDARD_IA",
        "ONEZONE_IA",
        "INTELLIGENT_TIERING",
        "GLACIER",
        "DEEP_ARCHIVE",
        "OUTPOSTS",
    }
}
```

I assume this is due to the fact that the code is generated and based on some common representation that is used to create SDKs for various languages,

In my opinion, the one-liner is the way to go, because it avoids introducing an unused variable:

```golang
s3Types.StorageClassStandard.Values()
```

Introducing a new variable would however highlight the fact that there is no meaning to the value which is used when invoking the `Values()` method.